# Compiling code copied verbatim from book causes compiler errors

Tags: c, cocoa, new-operator

I am working from a book on Cocoa and Objective-C. I followed a book exercise and I'm sure I've written the code exactly like the code in the book. However, I get compiler errors when I compile the code. Even when I copy-and-paste it from the book PDF I still get compilation errors.

Here is the command line and the output:

```
-MacBook-Pro:ch03 CauldronPoint$ gcc SongTest2.c Song2.c -o SongTest
Song2.c:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before     
‘createSong’
Song2.c:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘theSong’
```

Here is the code:

```
//
//  Song2.h
//  

#ifndef _Song2_h
#define _Song2_h

typedef struct {
    char* title;
    int lengthInSeconds;
    int yearRecorded;
} Song;

Song createSong ( char* title, int length, int year );
void displaySong ( Song theSong );

#endif

//
//  Song2.c
//

#include <stdio.h>

Song createSong (char* title, int length, int year) {
    Song mySong;
    mySong.lengthInSeconds = length;
    mySong.yearRecorded = year;
    mySong.title = title;
    displaySong (mySong);
    return mySong;
}
void displaySong (Song theSong) {
    printf ("'%s' is %i seconds long ", theSong.title, theSong.lengthInSeconds);
    printf ("and was recorded in %i\n", theSong.yearRecorded);
}

//
//  SongTest2.c
//  

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Song2.h"

main () {
    Song allSongs[3];
    allSongs[0] = createSong ( "Hey Jude", 210, 2004 );
    allSongs[1] = createSong ( "Jambi", 256, 1992 );
    allSongs[2] = createSong ( "Lightning Crashes", 223, 1997 );
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to complile without the errors?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the header file `Song2.h` in `Song2.c`.
The compiler complains because it does not understand the type of `Song`.

```
//
//  Song2.c
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Song2.h"
```